# How to compile and run C code in GVim on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, vim, for-loop, mingw

I'm using GVim on Windows 7 and trying to compile and run my code right in Vim(just like in visual studio). 
I've installed minGW, and correctly set the Environment Variable of Windows.
Look at the image below, when i click the shovel, whose function is to "make current project", error message appear(in lower part of screen).
[image]
How to fix this~~ thanks^^

Comment: as the massage states, you don't have make in your path, consider installing cygwin to get it (or add it to your path) minGW is *just* a compiler. BTW the "shovel" is a hammer, like the one you use when you *make* things :-)

Comment: I know little about compilers. Isn't cygwin just a compiler?

Comment: NO Cygwin is a Linux-like environment for Windows making it possible to port software running on POSIX systems (such as Linux, BSD, and Unix systems) to Windows. You will get a terminal with bash-shell per default and the ability to run every linux program there is in a windows environment, including the **make** command.

Comment: Ok, i have installed Cygwin and set F:\Programming\Cygwin\bin in the environment variable, but the same error appears. 1.Should i do sth else instead of clicking the "shovel"? 2.is the path ...Cygwin\bin wrong?

Comment: did you add **make**? it's not included by default in cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

Try [vim-quickrun](https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun) plugin.

Write C++ code in the buffer (it should have `cpp` filetype), and try

```
:QuickRun
```

I use vim-quickrun always. I add following in my `.vimrc`.

```
silent! nnoremap <unique> <silent> <leader>r :<c-u>QuickRun<cr>
```